# How to suppress space between two specific paragraphs only

Tags: environments, paragraphs

I defined a new `commentaire` environment to one of my projet in order to bring enlightment to a specific paragraph of the document. It takes as entry the author of the comment and obviously the text.
It works fine. Though, i have an issue regarding the display. I don't want the comment to be separated from the paragraph above, but i want a paragraph break after the comment, basically exactly the opposite of the following output:
[image: what i want, no paragraph break and addition of a paragraph break after (author)]

Using the `samepage` environment already fixed the separation of the comment from the upper paragraph (it's linked paragraph) on another page but it still does this linebreak with vertical space (sorry for my English) between the upper paragraph and the comment and the linebreak (code l. 36) doesn't seems to make the comment being a separated paragraph from the one bellow.

So here is a MWE: (checkout output page 2), sorry for the super long text, i needed a lot of text to show the issue.

```
\documentclass[french, 11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newenvironment{commentaire}[1]
{
\nopagebreak
\newcommand{\footArg}{#1}
\paragraph{\faCommentsO}
}
{
~(\footArg)
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.
Morbi a lacinia nunc, sed ornare justo. Integer consequat sem purus, nec bibendum turpis ultrices quis. Cras nisl felis, ultricies vitae faucibus posuere, vestibulum id enim. Etiam pellentesque enim egestas, ornare diam id, ullamcorper ex. Pellentesque laoreet nisl pretium nisl tincidunt, non pharetra elit tempus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse a odio dui. Etiam ac est vitae tortor elementum imperdiet in non diam. Mauris fermentum nec nisl tristique sollicitudin. Morbi vel tristique purus.

Nam elementum erat et orci venenatis aliquet. Morbi vel ligula nisl. Vivamus nec turpis id elit tempus facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris id est condimentum, sollicitudin dolor sit amet, lacinia ligula. Etiam luctus quis lacus facilisis tempus. Maecenas viverra felis porttitor nunc vestibulum aliquet. Duis efficitur tortor sit amet sem placerat, vitae cursus mi finibus. Ut elementum enim feugiat, pretium orci id, tincidunt augue. Nunc in sollicitudin mauris.

\begin{samepage}
Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In lacinia est enim, non vulputate purus iaculis ut. Sed dictum magna quis pretium elementum. Sed in ante diam. Nam vitae tellus non dui imperdiet feugiat id ac nisi. Praesent est dolor, fermentum sed mattis sed, tempor vitae purus. Curabitur posuere, justo ac tincidunt accumsan, est sapien aliquet purus, malesuada sagittis magna velit ut est. Mauris posuere, tellus et congue fermentum, ipsum enim facilisis sapien, ultricies pharetra nisl velit non lectus. Maecenas pretium ex eget est dignissim, et commodo libero efficitur. Curabitur a ullamcorper mi, sit amet pharetra odio. Nullam purus metus, ullamcorper mattis urna eget, ornare molestie ante. Pellentesque eu interdum augue. Sed in sem luctus, bibendum arcu vel, sollicitudin arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nam nulla leo, pellentesque vel vehicula a, rutrum in nisl. Morbi a ipsum sapien.
    \begin{commentaire}{author}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.
    \end{commentaire}
\end{samepage}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.

Sed viverra venenatis pretium. Sed a faucibus sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mauris risus, luctus ut ipsum a, euismod viverra tortor. Sed dapibus leo nec tortor rhoncus egestas. Sed nisi velit, faucibus eget tellus nec, fringilla pellentesque elit. Morbi et justo mattis, volutpat arcu a, fermentum lacus. In nec pharetra purus.

Morbi a lacinia nunc, sed ornare justo. Integer consequat sem purus, nec bibendum turpis ultrices quis. Cras nisl felis, ultricies vitae faucibus posuere, vestibulum id enim. Etiam pellentesque enim egestas, ornare diam id, ullamcorper ex. Pellentesque laoreet nisl pretium nisl tincidunt, non pharetra elit tempus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse a odio dui. Etiam ac est vitae tortor elementum imperdiet in non diam. Mauris fermentum nec nisl tristique sollicitudin. Morbi vel tristique purus.

Nam elementum erat et orci venenatis aliquet. Morbi vel ligula nisl. Vivamus nec turpis id elit tempus facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris id est condimentum, sollicitudin dolor sit amet, lacinia ligula. Etiam luctus quis lacus facilisis tempus. Maecenas viverra felis porttitor nunc vestibulum aliquet. Duis efficitur tortor sit amet sem placerat, vitae cursus mi finibus. Ut elementum enim feugiat, pretium orci id, tincidunt augue. Nunc in sollicitudin mauris.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In lacinia est enim, non vulputate purus iaculis ut. Sed dictum magna quis pretium elementum. Sed in ante diam. Nam vitae tellus non dui imperdiet feugiat id ac nisi. Praesent est dolor, fermentum sed mattis sed, tempor vitae purus. Curabitur posuere, justo ac tincidunt accumsan, est sapien aliquet purus, malesuada sagittis magna velit ut est. Mauris posuere, tellus et congue fermentum, ipsum enim facilisis sapien, ultricies pharetra nisl velit non lectus. Maecenas pretium ex eget est dignissim, et commodo libero efficitur. Curabitur a ullamcorper mi, sit amet pharetra odio. Nullam purus metus, ullamcorper mattis urna eget, ornare molestie ante. Pellentesque eu interdum augue. Sed in sem luctus, bibendum arcu vel, sollicitudin arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nam nulla leo, pellentesque vel vehicula a, rutrum in nisl. Morbi a ipsum sapien.
\end{document}
```

How to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `lipsum` package to generate the dummy text ;)

Comment: Thanks i know about it :) I just needed to be able to select the last paragraph. But there were workaround indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid abusing `\paragraph`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newenvironment{commentaire}[1]
 {%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \newcommand{\footArg}{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\parindent][l]{\faCommentsO}}\ignorespaces
 }
 {\unskip~(\footArg)\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.
Morbi a lacinia nunc, sed ornare justo. Integer consequat sem purus, nec bibendum turpis ultrices quis. Cras nisl felis, ultricies vitae faucibus posuere, vestibulum id enim. Etiam pellentesque enim egestas, ornare diam id, ullamcorper ex. Pellentesque laoreet nisl pretium nisl tincidunt, non pharetra elit tempus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse a odio dui. Etiam ac est vitae tortor elementum imperdiet in non diam. Mauris fermentum nec nisl tristique sollicitudin. Morbi vel tristique purus.

Nam elementum erat et orci venenatis aliquet. Morbi vel ligula nisl. Vivamus nec turpis id elit tempus facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris id est condimentum, sollicitudin dolor sit amet, lacinia ligula. Etiam luctus quis lacus facilisis tempus. Maecenas viverra felis porttitor nunc vestibulum aliquet. Duis efficitur tortor sit amet sem placerat, vitae cursus mi finibus. Ut elementum enim feugiat, pretium orci id, tincidunt augue. Nunc in sollicitudin mauris.

\begin{samepage}
Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In lacinia est enim, non vulputate purus iaculis ut. Sed dictum magna quis pretium elementum. Sed in ante diam. Nam vitae tellus non dui imperdiet feugiat id ac nisi. Praesent est dolor, fermentum sed mattis sed, tempor vitae purus. Curabitur posuere, justo ac tincidunt accumsan, est sapien aliquet purus, malesuada sagittis magna velit ut est. Mauris posuere, tellus et congue fermentum, ipsum enim facilisis sapien, ultricies pharetra nisl velit non lectus. Maecenas pretium ex eget est dignissim, et commodo libero efficitur. Curabitur a ullamcorper mi, sit amet pharetra odio. Nullam purus metus, ullamcorper mattis urna eget, ornare molestie ante. Pellentesque eu interdum augue. Sed in sem luctus, bibendum arcu vel, sollicitudin arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nam nulla leo, pellentesque vel vehicula a, rutrum in nisl. Morbi a ipsum sapien.
    \begin{commentaire}{author}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.
    \end{commentaire}
\end{samepage}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mauris lacus, rhoncus eget feugiat ac, vestibulum eu nisl. Nam accumsan et mi quis vehicula. Nunc eu nisi ullamcorper, bibendum arcu a, mollis lectus. Praesent et hendrerit augue. Donec dapibus tortor ut purus faucibus auctor. Sed viverra eget lorem ac vehicula. Etiam faucibus dictum interdum. Quisque sed fringilla nibh. Aliquam eleifend, nunc sed malesuada egestas, nulla lacus egestas mi, quis egestas eros velit sed mauris. Proin ornare lacus tincidunt dapibus scelerisque. Ut fringilla ultrices purus vel dictum.

Sed viverra venenatis pretium. Sed a faucibus sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mauris risus, luctus ut ipsum a, euismod viverra tortor. Sed dapibus leo nec tortor rhoncus egestas. Sed nisi velit, faucibus eget tellus nec, fringilla pellentesque elit. Morbi et justo mattis, volutpat arcu a, fermentum lacus. In nec pharetra purus.

Morbi a lacinia nunc, sed ornare justo. Integer consequat sem purus, nec bibendum turpis ultrices quis. Cras nisl felis, ultricies vitae faucibus posuere, vestibulum id enim. Etiam pellentesque enim egestas, ornare diam id, ullamcorper ex. Pellentesque laoreet nisl pretium nisl tincidunt, non pharetra elit tempus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse a odio dui. Etiam ac est vitae tortor elementum imperdiet in non diam. Mauris fermentum nec nisl tristique sollicitudin. Morbi vel tristique purus.

Nam elementum erat et orci venenatis aliquet. Morbi vel ligula nisl. Vivamus nec turpis id elit tempus facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris id est condimentum, sollicitudin dolor sit amet, lacinia ligula. Etiam luctus quis lacus facilisis tempus. Maecenas viverra felis porttitor nunc vestibulum aliquet. Duis efficitur tortor sit amet sem placerat, vitae cursus mi finibus. Ut elementum enim feugiat, pretium orci id, tincidunt augue. Nunc in sollicitudin mauris.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In lacinia est enim, non vulputate purus iaculis ut. Sed dictum magna quis pretium elementum. Sed in ante diam. Nam vitae tellus non dui imperdiet feugiat id ac nisi. Praesent est dolor, fermentum sed mattis sed, tempor vitae purus. Curabitur posuere, justo ac tincidunt accumsan, est sapien aliquet purus, malesuada sagittis magna velit ut est. Mauris posuere, tellus et congue fermentum, ipsum enim facilisis sapien, ultricies pharetra nisl velit non lectus. Maecenas pretium ex eget est dignissim, et commodo libero efficitur. Curabitur a ullamcorper mi, sit amet pharetra odio. Nullam purus metus, ullamcorper mattis urna eget, ornare molestie ante. Pellentesque eu interdum augue. Sed in sem luctus, bibendum arcu vel, sollicitudin arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nam nulla leo, pellentesque vel vehicula a, rutrum in nisl. Morbi a ipsum sapien.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `commentaire` environment basically does a `\paragraph`, which has that spacing predefined:

```
\newcommand\paragraph{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}% <- Indentation
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}% <- Space before
  {-1em}% <- Space after (if negative, then doesn't do a line rbeak)
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}% <- Format
```

so we have to change the `commentaire` environment to add these spaces in the correct spot.

The argument to `\paragraph` is typeset with `Format`, before it there is an `Indentation` (`\z@`), and after it an horizontal space of `Space after` (`1em`), so we can write:

```
  \par\noindent% No indentation
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries% Format
   \faCommentsO}\hskip1em\relax% Space after
```

then, when the environment ends, we want the `Space before`:

```
  \par
  \addvspace{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
```

putting it all together, the `commentaire` environment will look like:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{commentaire}[1]
{%
  \nopagebreak
  \newcommand{\footArg}{#1}%
  \par\noindent
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries
   \faCommentsO}\hskip1em\relax
}{%
  ~(\footArg)%
  \par
  \addvspace{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
}
\makeatother
```

and the output:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks!
Indeed I want to redefine all `commentaire` environments.
I added your command lines to the preamble of the file but it doesn't seem to afect anything, neither the other paragraphs or the commentaire `environment`.
There is still no skip after the commentaire.

Comment: Ooh, hold on a little then :)

Comment: @Odyseus_v4 There, done :)